# Trying to break apart files to make code easier to read; any shortcuts to avoid excessive indentation?

Tags: c#, formatting, indentation, shorthand

I'm working on a project where we're nesting somewhat complex classes within other classes, and it has come to the point where breaking these up into separate files may help us maintain some sort of order over the mess.

But, with a single nested class, even if a file contains nothing else (no other classes), I'm still having to prefix each line with three levels of indentation, which makes hitting the limits of horizontal readability too easy, even with simple statements (albeit many with long function/class/variable names).

The file might look like this:

```
namespace Example.Namespace1
{
    public partial class ImportantClass
    {
        protected partial class Nested1
        {
            // I can finally start writing code here
            public int AddOffset(int offset)
            {
                // Code inside of a method
            }

            public string ID{ get; protected set; }
        }
    }
}
```

So, do I have any shortcuts to declaring `Nested1` that can save me some horizontal space (e.g. `protected partial class ImportantClass.Nested1` doesn't work, but something like that)?

Comment: You mean, aside from not nesting?

Comment: You can put everything onto a single line, that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the answer is **No**.

We have some alternate approaches here, but to the answer to the question: *Does C# have any shorthand notation for nested classes?* **No**, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it.

Use the class nesting sparingly just for simple internal use classes. The fact that you are trying to split them out into different files tells you something - ie that you have gone a bit overboard with the nested classes.

Using them publicly out side of your code is ugly ugly.

If you need to keep things internal use the internal modifier. Name spaces and project folders can help you keep everything organized.

Comment: My options are to clutter up the `ImportantClass` namespace with the new functions that don't seem like they belong there or to wrap them up in a nested class to at least give some sense of separation.  I don't have the option to re-factor into namespaces since this isn't my pet project.

Comment: Why not put a namespace underneath the Example.Namespace1 namespace - that is namespace Example.Namespace1.InternalStuff { class MyFormalyInternalClass {...

Comment: One more question - do you intend for these classes to be used outside of the assembly? If they are internal only mark them internal and they will not be part of the public interface of your assembly.

Comment: @palswim, ImportantClass is "cluttered" at least as much with a nested class of n methods as it would be if it just contained the n methods directly.